# Vue Js define Iterator

Tags: vue.js

How can we define new iterator like v-for (for example v-for2) that iterate over an array ?
I want to accumulate one property of array items.
the result would be like this :

```
<div v-for2="(item, accumulated) in [1,2,3,4,5,6]">
    {{accumulated}}
</div>
```

Comment: Create custom directive.

Comment: It is clear from the question, that i should use custom directive. the point is how to use it.